# MongoDB not returning index score on query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an application with multiple backend services running nodejs. I´m using MongoDB text indexes on 2 fields and it works great. The thing is i need mongoDB to return index score on queries so i can compare the relevance of the results, not just ordering them. Mongo correctly return the scores when i query from the database shell:

```
> db.locations.find({ $text: {$search: "comarca"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).toArray()
[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60a18f9299399d92de4b4972"),
                "name" : "La Comarca",
                "relatedIndividuals" : [
                        "Frodo Bolsón",
                ],

                "score" : 5
        }
]
```

But when I make the query from nodejs like this:

```
getDb().collection('locations').find({ $text: {$search: searchString}},{ score:{ $meta: "textScore"}}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs)
        resolve (docs);
    })
```

I get:

```
[{ 
    _id: '60a18f9299399d92de4b4972',
    name: 'La Comarca',
    relatedIndividuals:
    [ 
        'Frodo Bolsón'
    ],
}]
```

whiout the score.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Going by what I read on the documentation, try this instead.

```
getDb().collection('locations').find({ $text: {$search: searchString}} ).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
```

Comment: Hello, that returns exactly what i posted without the score. I assume that if mongo finds multiple documents the sorting is apply. But no scoring field is returne

Comment: @Knemay That's surprising, do you mind posting the code after the change and result. I am curious.

Comment: What's the version of MongoDB in use and driver version.

Comment: Here is the code after the change: ` getDb().collection('locations').find({ $text: {$search: searchString}},{ score:{ $meta: "textScore"}}).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs)
        resolve (docs);
    })`. The result is the same I posted in the question

Comment: Remove the score from first part, keep it only in the sort. @Knemay
getDb().collection('locations').find({ $text: {$search: searchString}}).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } }).toArray(function (err, docs) { console.log(docs) resolve (docs); })`